# ROWID on oracle table

Tags: oracle, join, rowid

When I executed below SQL, I get rowid as : `AAAI4cAAJAAAzWzAAA`

```
SELECT Y.ROWID, Y.res_dt, Y.res_cd
  FROM AJ_CES X
       INNER JOIN temp_stg Y
          ON     X.key_field = Y.key_field
             AND X.sts_cd IN ('P', 'G')
             AND X.proc_dt >= Y.e_date
```

But, if I execute below SQL,  I get rowids as below, both are same rowid which is not expected.

```
SELECT A.ROWID, B.ROWID
  FROM AJ_CES A
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Y.ROWID, Y.res_dt, Y.res_cd
                     FROM AJ_CES X
                          INNER JOIN temp_stg Y
                             ON     X.key_field = Y.key_field
                                AND X.sts_cd IN ('P', 'G')
                                AND X.proc_dt >= Y.e_date) B
          ON (A.ROWID = B.ROWID)
```

As we saw in the first SQL, rowid is `AAAI4cAAJAAAzWzAAA. First sql is subquery from the 2nd sql which was executed separately to see the rowid. 
So, 
in 2nd SQL, B is nothing but rowid from temp_stg and if we join this rowid with outer table AJ_CES, why both rowids same?

See below output:

```
ROWID                    ROWID1
AAAJC9AANAAEputAAA       AAAJC9AANAAEputAAA
```

Comment: Does the first query only give one row?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the DDL for the tables, and the exact version of Oracle you are seeing this in?

Comment: It gives one row as consition is matching with one row only

Comment: Hi. This is not clear. Also your code is incomplete.Please read & act on [mcve]. That includes a clear specification & desired output for given input & explanation. Please edit clarifications into posts, not comments.

Comment: To understand the issue, you must understand the sqls posted that's it.